# Formio how to download the record that is created using form io form?

Tags: formio

After creating the web form using the form-io and created a record out of it how can I get that form in pdf? is there any tag that i can use or do we need to use any other third party npm package for this?

Comment: If it's form.io then you have some PDF support, check the documentation https://help.form.io/userguide/pdf/

Comment: I cannot "help" you, integrating a library into a project. Please try on your own, if you fail or encounter some difficulties along the way, search for answers, if there are no answers please post questions, one for each issue in hand.